# Nokia here map data for Android - download on pc and move to phone

Tags: gps-tracking, maps

This question is very specific to Nokia Here Map on Android Lollypop.
I have installed the app on the phone, however my wifi is too slow to download the offline map using the app.

I am looking for a way to download the offline map data on my computer using ethernet and later load onto sd card and then app could point the same map.

the issues I am facing:
1) Can I download the map onto PC as raw map data file? I am looking for a trusted source.

2) Once downloaded,  where to copy on the disk, so that app can point to the location?

Please note that I do not want to switch to any other map, so kindly do not suggest the same.

Comment: Reverse tether from the PC to the phone?

Comment: @gyan, I could see you accepted the answer as a solution. Did you try copying the folders yourself or used any app? Explaining that as an update will help other users in future.

Comment: Hi Narayana, I did used Andy and able to download the maps. Then I moved those map files to android phone. The only challenge was that Andy is a still having lower version than the android release, so not sure if this workaround would still work with latest android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could suggest you to use an emulator like [Andy](http://www.andyroid.net/). Using this will help you to use your computer's Ethernet to access Internet.

You can install the app on that emulator and download the map data. Then you can either identify the download area and copy them to your phone. If that's too cumbersome you can rely on apps like titanium backup to restore the data alone.

It would be helpful for you if you use the same Android version on both emulator and phone.